# how to get teams context in Spfx react solution

Tags: microsoft-teams, spfx

How to get teams context in Spfx react solution?

Here is the method to get ms teams message using msgraphclientFactory

[image: method that to get ms teams message using msgraphclientFactory]

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to access context information within teams through tab context and bot context. Please follow up with the documentation for [Tab context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-context) and [Bot Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-context).